# I need loadLibrary two so library files on Android Studio v1.1.0

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I had an examples for two so files for one app which is very simple, and I just have tried to do same code on Android Studio 1.1.0.
I refer many web sites, so I put my so files on "src/main/jniLis/[arch]/" and run my app. But it was failed. This is error log from ddms.

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mdsedu.twolibstatic-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mdsedu.twolibstatic-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtwolib-first.so
```

This is the part of java code. (It's similar as jni sample "two-lib".)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ ...
    System.loadLibrary("twolib-first");
    System.loadLibrary("twolib-second");
    int sum = nativeAdd(x, y); ...
}
public native int nativeAdd(int  x, int  y);
```

This is the Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-first
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-second
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := second.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtwolib-first
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I didn't modiify build.gradle file.

I tried to compress lib/[arch]/*.so files and convert to jar files, but it was not working neither.

Would anybody please help me for my two-lib samples on Android Studio? I just started Android Studio a few days ago. 
please apologize me if I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

you have two solutions to use more than one ndk lib from an Android Studio project.

**1)** remove the jni folder from your Android Studio project, compile your .so files from anywhere outside of your Android studio project, directly using ndk-build, and put them under `src/main/jniLibs/(armeabi-v7a, x86, ...)/`

**2)** keep your jni folder with your sources and Makefiles, deactivate the built-in call to ndk-build, change the location of jniLibs to libs, and add a call to ndk-build. In summary, put this inside your *build.gradle* file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files directory to libs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}
```

If you're still encountering issues, look if your .so files are getting properly packaged inside your APK, under `lib/(armeabi-v7a, x86, ...)`, by opening it as a zip file. If that's the case, the issue isn't on packaging.